# what should I do if I want a logged out user still can access the content anonymously using firebase authentication?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

so I want to make a new user can see some contents in my app before they decide to actually login.

I need to implement [sign in anonymously](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth) for a new user before they login, because In my firebase security rules, there is a rule state that the user is must be logged in like this

```
function isSignedIn() {
      return request.auth != null;
}
```

1) first, after installing the app, a new user comes and then logged in anonymously using the code below, and let say the userID for this anonymous user is A1a2A3a4A5a6A7

```
Auth.auth().signInAnonymously() { (authResult, error) in
   // create anonymous user wih uid == A1a2A3a4A5a6A7
}
```

2) and then this user decides to login using real email, no longer anonymous, using google account, then I link it using the code below. now that user A1a2A3a4A5a6A7 login provider is become google account

```
let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

 Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in 
     // A1a2A3a4A5a6A7 is now using google account as the provider
 }
```

3) then this user performs logout using this code below:

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
```

here is the problem .....

to make this user still can see some content in my app, I have to make this user sign in again, right ?

then what should I do for this logged out registered user ?

do I have to perform signAnonymously again ? but this will create a new different userID right ? I am worried it will make a double account if a new userID is created.

or can I change the registered user authentication provider from login using google account, to be back to anonymous. in order to keep the userID the same.

I don't know if there is a better way, what should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Someone at Firebase gave a thought at this scenario. You can allow users to sign in to your app using multiple authentication providers by linking auth provider credentials to an existing user account. Users are identifiable by the same Firebase user ID regardless of the authentication provider they used to sign in. For example, a user who signed in with a password can link a Google account and sign in with either method in the future. Or, an anonymous user can link a Facebook account and then, later, sign in with Facebook to continue using your app. Details [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking)

Comment: so in my case, I should not convert from anonymous to be google account as the provider, but I should add the google account as the provider, so one userID will have both google account and anonymous as the provider ?

Comment: That’s right. Don’t “convert” anything. Just pink the two accounts. As I understand if UID of anonymous is say “a1b2..” then irrespective of whether user uses his/her google account you will get the same UID (i.e. “a1b2”)

Comment: but the problem is .....when the user a1b2 logout from their google account, then how to signinanonymously() with the uid of a1b2 ? because as I understand, if I use signinanonymously(), the sdk will give a new uid. i think it is important, because if I have a new uid then it will be a lot of anonymous user

Comment: Let’s say a user sign in anonymously on a particular device. Then he uses his google account to sign in. He logs out. And again sign in anonymously on the same device. Now in these three logins you will get UID as “a1b2” (provided you link the account).